# How to compare two different tables based on two different Columns in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

The first table consists of Accounts with State and Country information which are mostly correct with few wrong rows:

```
ID   NAME            State                  Country
--------------------------------------------------
1    Account 1       NJ                     USA
2    Account 2       NY                     NULL
3    Account 3       Beijing                Japan
```

And I have the second table which has the correct state and County information to which the first tables needs to be compared to:

```
State_Code        State     Country_Code       Country
-------------------------------------------------------
01                NJ          A01               USA
02                NY          A01               USA
03                Beijing     c01               China
```

The query should check if the state in the first table exists in the second table and if it does, is it associated with the correct country and the result would be a table of rows with wrong info:

So in my example, the comparison should give me the result:

```
ID     NAME         State                  Country
------------------------------------------------------
 2     Account 2    NY                     NULL
 3     Account 3    Beijing                Japan
```

I am a beginner trying to learn more about SQL and I tried solving this using left join and outer join both of which didn't give me the correct result. I would be very grateful if some one could point me in the right direction or give me an example on how I should approach this.

(I am using Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio)

Comment: Why do NY and NJ have different country_codes but same country?

Comment: Show us your current query attempt.

Comment: Sorry, my bad. Corrected now.

Comment: Seems like a poor table design to store both country_code and country in that table. Keep country_code, skip country. (Normalization!)

Comment: Thanks for your reply. The left join I tried is :    SELECT a.id,a.name,a.State, a.Country FROM [Accounts] a LEFT JOIN [State_And_Country] b ON a.State!=b.State AND a.Country!=b.Country. After removing the incorrect rows, these tables will be moved to a different system and removed from database. So is normalization necessary for this operation since I wouldn't have to maintain this in the database for long?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try this.  You can change the join condition if you need any changes.

**Data**

```
CREATE TABLE firstTable
(
     ID  INT    
    ,NAME    VARCHAR(10)           
    ,State    VARCHAR(10)                    
    ,Country VARCHAR(10)     
)
GO

INSERT INTO firstTable VALUES
(1    ,'Account 1','NJ','USA'),
(2    ,'Account 2','NY',NULL),
(3    ,'Account 3','Beijing','Japan')
GO

CREATE TABLE SecondTable
(
     State_Code  VARCHAR(10)     
    ,State      VARCHAR(10)
    ,Country_Code      VARCHAR(10)
    ,Country VARCHAR(10)
)
GO

INSERT INTO SecondTable VALUES
('01','NJ'          ,'A01','USA'),
('02','NY'          ,'A01','USA'),
('03','Beijing'     ,'c01','China')  
GO
```

**SOLUTION**

```
select f.* from firstTable f
FULL JOIN SecondTable s
ON f.State = s.State and f.Country = s.Country
WHERE f.State IS NOT NULL AND ( s.Country_Code IS NULL OR s.State IS NULL )
```

**OUTPUT**

```
ID          NAME       State      Country
----------- ---------- ---------- ----------
2           Account 2  NY         NULL
3           Account 3  Beijing    Japan

(2 rows affected)
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to join the two tables on the State and look for records where the Country doesn't match.  This query should get you there:

```
SELECT t1.*, t2. Country AS Expected
FROM table1 t1
JOIN table2 t2 ON t1.State = t2.State
WHERE t1.County != t2.Country
```

Unfortunately, I don't know your table names, so I just had to go with table1 and table2, but hopefully this gives you what you need.  I also added in the expected Country, but you can remove that if you don't need it.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you're looking for is "NOT EXISTS".  Basically you look for any state/country combos in the first table that don't exist in the second table.  Here's an example.

```
SELECT tbo.ID, tbo.NAME, tbo.STATE, tbo.COUNTRY
FROM TableOne tbo
WHERE NOT EXISTS(
    SELECT * FROM TableTwo tbt
    WHERE tbo.State = tbt.State
        AND tbo.Country = tbt.Country
)
```